# Spring @Autowired field is null inside an overrided method

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I have a class that implements MessageListener for the use with Spring Data Redis. It works fine with Redis but I have a strange behavior. I have a test() method that test if the messageService instance is null or not. It needs to call the Jpa Repository for the persistence in MySql DB. The strange behavior is that it ins't null if it is invoked inside getNewMessage() and printWelcome() methods (and then I can use CRUD methods for the persistence), but it is **null** inside the onMessage() method overrided by the org.springframework.data.redis.connection.MessageListener class.This is my Controller class:

```
@Controller
public class StatoController implements MessageListener{


  @Autowired
  private MessageService messageService;

  public static final List<DeferredResult<Message>> messageDeferredResultList = new ArrayList<>();

  @RequestMapping(value = "sec/redis", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
  @ResponseBody
  public DeferredResult<Message> getNewMessage() throws Exception {
    Long deferredResultTimeout = 0L;

    final DeferredResult<Message> deferredResult = new DeferredResult<>(deferredResultTimeout);

    deferredResult.onCompletion(() -> {
        messageDeferredResultList.remove(deferredResult);
    });

    deferredResult.onTimeout(() -> {
        messageDeferredResultList.remove(deferredResult);
    });

    messageDeferredResultList.add(deferredResult);

    try{
        //not null
        List<Message> list=messageService.findAll();
    }
    catch(Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();}

    return deferredResult;
  }

  @RequestMapping(value = {"sec/stato.html"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public ModelAndView printWelcome(ModelMap model) {

    try{
        //not null
        List<Message> list=messageService.findAll();
    }
    catch(Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();}

    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("secured/stato");
    return mav;
  }


  @Override
  public void onMessage(Message msg, byte[] bytes) {

    try{
        //NullPointerException
        List<Message> list=messageService.findAll();
    }
    catch(Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();}
    // set the deferred results for the user
    messageDeferredResultList.stream().forEach((deferredResult) -> {
        deferredResult.setResult(msg);
    });

  }
```

This is the stacktrace when a message arrives and the onMessage method is called:

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at infn.lns.acceleratori.controller.StatoController.onMessage(StatoController.java:95)
>       at org.springframework.data.redis.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessageListenerAdapter.java:299)
>       at org.springframework.data.redis.listener.RedisMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(RedisMessageListenerContainer.java:245)
>       at org.springframework.data.redis.listener.RedisMessageListenerContainer.processMessage(RedisMessageListenerContainer.java:235)
>       at org.springframework.data.redis.listener.RedisMessageListenerContainer$1.run(RedisMessageListenerContainer.java:960)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

The onMessage() method is called when there is a message from Redis. I correctly added this in my context-config.xml:

```
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="org.springframework.data.redis, infn.lns.acceleratori"/>
```

This is the configuration class that contains the bean declaration for data redis:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

  @Bean
  JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
    return new JedisConnectionFactory();
  }

  @Bean
  RedisTemplate< String, Object > redisTemplate() {
    final RedisTemplate< String, Object > template =  new RedisTemplate<  >();
    template.setConnectionFactory( jedisConnectionFactory() );
    template.setKeySerializer( new StringRedisSerializer() );
    template.setHashValueSerializer( new GenericToStringSerializer<  >( Object.class ) );
    template.setValueSerializer( new GenericToStringSerializer<  >( Object.class ) );
    return template;
  }

  @Bean
  MessageListenerAdapter messageListener() {
    return new MessageListenerAdapter( new RedisMessageListener() );
  }

  @Bean
  RedisMessageListenerContainer redisContainer() {
    final RedisMessageListenerContainer container = new RedisMessageListenerContainer();

    container.setConnectionFactory( jedisConnectionFactory() );
    container.addMessageListener( messageListener(), new ChannelTopic( "queue" ) );

    return container;
  }

}
```

This is the MessageServiceImpl created as Bean:

```
@Service
public class MessageServiceImpl implements MessageService {

  @Resource
  private MessageRepository messageRepository;

  @Override
  @Transactional
  public Message create(Message event) {
    Message createdMessage = event;
    return messageRepository.save(createdMessage);
  }
```

I want to know why the instance of messageRepository is correctly autowired in getNewMessage() and printWelcome() methods but not in the overrided onMessage() method.

**EDIT:**

Now I split my listener and my controller in two different classes. I have this new class:

```
public class RedisMessageListener implements MessageListener {

  @Autowired
  private MessageService messageService;

  @Override
  public void onMessage(Message message, byte[] paramArrayOfByte) {
    System.out.println(messageService==null);

    messageDeferredResultList.stream().forEach((deferredResult) -> {
        deferredResult.setResult(message);
    });
  }
}
```

but messageService is always null. It is just a bean!

Comment: can you please add stacktrace? and what you mean with *I want to know why the instance is correctly autowired in these methods but not in the overrided method*?? you autowire `messageRepository` which is not used in overriden method....

Comment: Sorry I have modified my question. I added the stacktrace: the instance of messageRepository is null inside onMessageMethod, while it is not null inside the other two methods and I don't know why.

Comment: Because you are creating an instance yourself, that instance isn't a bean. Also why on earth is your controller (which is web related) also a listener? imho those should be 2 separate things.

Comment: I don't understand why inside the controller the messageService is correctly autowired, but not in the listener class. It is just a bean thnaks to Service tag above public class MessageServiceImpl implements MessageService

Comment: Where do you now create the RedisMessageListener bean?

Comment: @Bean
  MessageListenerAdapter messageListener() {
    return new MessageListenerAdapter( new RedisMessageListener() );
  }
inside another package

Comment: Ok, so you still create the instance of RedisMessageListener by yourself. Let Spring create it (by adding the `@Component` annotation) and inject it in the method where you create the MessageListenerAdapter.

Comment: You are right!!!! It was a banal error!!! Thank you very very much....

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the solution thanks to @dunni. I was still creating the instance of RedisMessageListener by myself. Allowing Spring creating it (by adding the @Component annotation) and injecting it in the method where I created the MessageListenerAdapter, using @Autowired, I solved the problem.

Comment: Can you please explain this a more

Answer (score 0):

@Vipul

that means your MessageListenerAdapter configuration create a TaskEventSubscriber bean by yourselft not by spring.

wrong:

```java
    @Bean
    MessageListenerAdapter taskEventListener() {
        MessageListenerAdapter messageListenerAdapter = new MessageListenerAdapter(new TaskEventSubscriber());
        return messageListenerAdapter;
    }
```

correct:

```java
@Autowired
private TaskEventSubscriber taskEventSubscriber;


@Bean
    MessageListenerAdapter taskEventListener() {
        MessageListenerAdapter messageListenerAdapter = new MessageListenerAdapter(taskEventSubscriber);
        RedisSerializer stringSerializer = new StringRedisSerializer();
        messageListenerAdapter.setSerializer(stringSerializer);
        return messageListenerAdapter;
    }
```

(sorry i cant not comment)